# Asp.Net MVC 4 login page returns json instead of view

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc-4, authentication

I'm building a Asp.Net MVC 4 application and I use the built-in login/register functionality. When I input wrong user name and password Chrome send me a page with html code instead of error messages. When I tried the same in IE it returns json document and ask me to save it. I have not changed the code of the Login action method. What could cause this?

edit:

It's enabled. I have that key in my web.config. This is the generated HTML of the login page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>Log in</title>
<link href="/favicon.png" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" />
<link href="/Content/styles/flexslider.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="/Content/styles/prettyPhoto.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="/Content/styles/style.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<link href="/Content/themes/custom/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.css" rel="stylesheet" />


<script src="/Scripts/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script src="/Scripts/portfolio-filter.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/all-in-one.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/setup.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/main.js"></script>

<script src="/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.js"></script>

<script src="/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js"></script>


</head>
<body>

<header class="header_bg clearfix">
    <div class="container clearfix">

        <div class="span2">

            <div>
                <ul class="social-links">
                    <li><a href="https://www.facebook.com/pages/Balkancar-Record-JSC/151365561578329?fref=ts" target="_blank">
                        <img src="/Content/images/facebook.png" alt="Facebook" /></a></li>
                    <li><a href="javascript:">
                        <img src="/Content/images/twitter.png" width="24" height="24" alt="Twitter" /></a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>


            <div class="lang-switch">
                <a href="#">English</a>
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <a href="/SetCulture/bg-BG?currentUrl=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A2487%2FAccount%2FLogin" id="bg-BG">Български</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="/SetCulture/en-US?currentUrl=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A2487%2FAccount%2FLogin" id="en-US">English</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="/SetCulture/ru-RU?currentUrl=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A2487%2FAccount%2FLogin" id="ru-RU">Руский</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>

            <section id="login">

                <ul>
                    <li><a href="/Account/Register" id="registerLink">Register</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/Account/Login" id="loginLink">Log in</a></li>
                </ul>

            </section>

            <div class="logo">
                <a href="/">
                    <img src="/Content/themes/base/images/BalkancarLogo.png" alt="Balkancar Record Co"
                        title="Balkancar Record Co" />
                </a>
            </div>



            <nav class="main-menu">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/Home/About">About us</a>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="/Home/History">History</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="/Products/Products">Products</a>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="/Products/Forklifts">Forklifts</a></li>
                            <li><a href="/Products/Electro">Electro</a></li>
                            <li><a href="/Products/TowTractors">Tow tractors</a></li>
                            <li><a href="/Products/ElectricPlatforms">Electric platforms</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="/Home/Sertificates">Sertificates</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/Home/Announcements">Announcements</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/Home/Dealers">Dealers</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/Home/Contact">Contacts</a>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="/Home/RequestQuote">Request a quote</a></li>
                            <li><a href="/Home/Departments">Departments</a></li>
                            <li><a href="/Home/Map">Map</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </nav>

        </div>
    </div>
</header>
<div class="clear"></div>

<section class="container clearfix">
    <header class="container page_info clearfix">
        <h1 class="regular bottom_line">Log in.</h1>
        <div class="clear"></div>
    </header>

    <div class="col_1_2">
        <h2>Use a local account to log in.</h2>
        <form action="/Account/Login" method="post">
            <input name="__RequestVerificationToken" type="hidden" value="pCU9vwbREtMyY-pBCdJqeu-af1sZwVrX6-LEIfKvoZIHr59qkwp_voncWYJaWyaKUGGJCVWObvG85aG9mEMvn1kjRT2RnOpY-9mI4XzDtq81" /><div class="validation-summary-errors">
                <ul>
                    <li>Wrong user name or password.</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <fieldset>
                <legend></legend>
                <p>
                    <label for="UserName">User name</label>
                    <input data-val="true" data-val-required="The User name field is required." id="UserName" name="UserName" type="text" value="jhg" />
                    <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="UserName" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
                </p>
                <p>
                    <label for="Password">Password</label>
                    <input data-val="true" data-val-required="The Password field is required." id="Password" name="Password" type="password" />
                    <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="Password" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
                </p>
                <p>
                    <input data-val="true" data-val-required="The Remember me? field is required." id="RememberMe" name="RememberMe" type="checkbox" value="true" /><input name="RememberMe" type="hidden" value="false" />
                    <label class="checkbox" for="RememberMe">Remember me?</label>
                </p>
                <input type="submit" value="Log in" />
            </fieldset>
            <p>
                <a href="/Account/Register">Register</a> if you don&#39;t have an account.
            </p>
        </form>
    </div>

    <div class="col_1_2 last">
        <section class="social" id="socialLoginForm">
            <h2>Use another service to log in.</h2>
            <form action="/Account/ExternalLogin?ReturnUrl=" method="post">
                <input name="__RequestVerificationToken" type="hidden" value="DRqkpbBT0xarOTdJjZ6NAOcZaPP9Xxx4_jOPeNhLFPGbOxxWEoxDx4NmN2lx4WxgZbYNe4VRBekPakyoXj6AmWKuW2XUV1yW5KC7QBpTMpQ1" />
                <fieldset id="socialLoginList">
                    <legend>Log in using another service</legend>
                    <p>
                        <button type="submit" name="provider" value="google" title="Log in using your Google account">Google</button>
                    </p>
                </fieldset>
            </form>
        </section>
    </div>

</section>

<div class="clear padding10"></div>
<section class="homepage_widgets_bg clearfix">
    <div class="container clearfix">
        <div class="padding20"></div>

        <div class="col_1_3">
            <h1 class="regular white bottom_line">Contacts</h1>
            <p id="contacts">
                &quot;Balkancar Record&quot; Co<br />
                17 &#39;&#39;Kuklensko Shosse&#39;&#39; str.<br />
                4004 Plovdiv<br />
                Phone: +359/32/ 69 50 50<br />
                Fax: +359/32/ 69 27 53<br />
                E-mail: <a href="mailto:record@balkancar-record.com">record@balkancar-record.com</a>
            </p>
        </div>
        <div class="col_1_3">
            <h1 class="regular white bottom_line">Follow us</h1>
            <a href="https://www.facebook.com/pages/Balkancar-Record-JSC/151365561578329?ref=ts&fref=ts" target="_blank">
                <img src="/Content/themes/base/images/facebook.png" alt="Facebook" />
            </a>
            <a href="http://www.youtube.com/user/BalkancarRecordJSC/videos" target="_blank">
                <img src="/Content/themes/base/images/youtube.png" alt="YouTube" />
            </a>

            <script type="text/javascript">
                window.___gcfg = {
                    lang: 'en-US'
                };

                (function () {
                    var po = document.createElement('script'); po.type = 'text/javascript'; po.async = true;
                    po.src = 'https://apis.google.com/js/plusone.js';
                    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(po, s);
                })();
            </script>
            <br />
        </div>
        <div class="col_1_3 last" id="why-section">
            <h1 class="regular white bottom_line">Subscribe</h1>
            {"Message":"Please fill in both fields!"}                
        </div>
        <div class="padding80"></div>
    </div>
</section>

<footer class="footer_bg_bottom clearfix">
    <div class="footer_bottom container">
        <div class="col_footer">
            <div class="menu">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/Home/About">About us</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/Products/Products">Products</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/Home/Sertificates">Sertificates</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/Home/Announcements">Announcements</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/Home/Dealers">Dealers</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/Home/Contact">Contacts</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="clear padding20"></div>
            <p>&copy; 2013 &quot;Balkancar Record&quot; Co</p>
            <p>Build version: 1.0.1408.805</p>
        </div>
        <div class="clear padding20"></div>
    </div>
</footer>

<script src="/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

> What could cause this?

Sounds like AJAX isn't enabled. Ensure `<add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />` is in your web.config.

If that doesn't fix it, show the generated HTML for your login page.

Comment: I figured it out where was the problem. In _Layout.cshtml I have a subscribe form and the action method that process the data from the form is returning a message in json format. Apparently I'm not processed correctly the message and the content-type of the page is changed to application/json.